# In c printf format of numbers will nor work in mrsh

Tags: c

Using `printf` format in for numbers which will work fine:

```
printf ("\r\n <%s>\t AmountOfMalloc %'.ld", HostName ,GetMalloc ()) ;
```

Output is like this, which is fine:

```
AmountOfMalloc 17.220.149.424
```

Calling the same app remote via mrsh in a script will cause no number format like this:

```
AmountOfMalloc 17220149424
```

Envirenment is Suse Linux Enterprise Server 15 sp2 in VMware Workstation 15.5.7 on Windows 10 ltsc 2019, 4 cores, 6GB ram.

Has someone expierienced this issue and a possible solution?

Comment: Please include output of `locale` command, both run locally and via mrsh.

Comment: Looks like different locale setting

Answer (score 1):

The difference is caused by different environment `locale` settings.

You can see the settings that are applied when the program runs the way you want by running `locale` command. It will output several lines for e.g. money and number format settings, but usually they all have the same value, such as `"en_US.UTF-8"`.

Easiest way to apply the setting to your remotely run command is to prefix the line like this:

```
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 /path/to/program
```

From the examples you provide, the locale you want is probably different than `en_US.UTF-8`, so use the value you get from `locale`.

Comment: locales are identical.LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=, setting LC_ALL wil not work for locale.

Comment: note that a C program starts with C locale by default. To use the environment locale, you _have to_ add `setlocale(LC_ALL, "")` to your program.

Comment: @KamilCuk Huh, I didn't know that. I wonder how it works with local running then.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot, locale was the problem. Did not see any reason why,

Adding the following to the c source before printf works fine:

```
setlocale ( LC_NUMERIC, "de_DE.UTF-8" ) ;
setlocale ( LC_ALL, "de_DE.UTF-8" ) ;
```

Thanks.